# What provides PageUtils and PagedIterable for the Bitbucket API?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I am trying to find what provides the packages:

```
com.atlassian.bitbucket.util.PageUtils;
com.atlassian.bitbucket.util.PagedIterable;
```

I have looked in:

[Bitbucket API](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/javadoc/6.2.0/api/reference/classes.html)

[Bitbucket SCM Common](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/javadoc/6.2.0/scm-common/reference/classes.html)

[Bitbucket SPI](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/javadoc/6.2.0/spi/reference/classes.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PageUtils` class is part of `bitbucket-util` jar. https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-external/com/atlassian/bitbucket/server/bitbucket-util/ 
Just add a dependency

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.bitbucket.server</groupId>
      <artifactId>bitbucket-util</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: @eeijlar glad to help